# Total number of Events on every date

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sqlite, t-sql

I am stuck developing a query.

I have a table, structured like this:

```
[EventId] [Description]  [EventName]    [ValidFrom]   [ValidTo]   [Approved]
1         Sample1        1stEvent       2013-01-27    2013-05-10     1
2         Sample2        2stEvent       2013-04-07    2013-06-15     1
3         Sample3        3stEvent       2013-04-07    2013-06-15     1
4         Sample4        4stEvent       2013-03-02    2013-05-29     1
5         Sample5        5stEvent       2013-05-17    2013-07-10     1
6         Sample6        6stEvent       2013-03-20    2013-05-11     1
```

What i want is the total number of events for every date within a date range, inclusive.

```
Select distinct 
    Convert(varchar,ValidFrom,101)as [Date],
    case 
        when count(EventID)>1 then Convert(nvarchar, count(EventID)) +' Events' 
        else Convert(nvarchar, count(EventID)) + ' Event'  
        end  as CountOf,
    Row_Number() 
        over (Order By Convert(varchar,ValidFrom,101)) as RowNumber 
from [Table]
where Approved=1  
group by Convert(varchar,ValidFrom,101)
```

This is the query I have come up with until now, but this shows the total number of events on a particular date without including the events which were continued as per the dates between valid from and valid to dates.

Comment: Can you supply desired results?  Not sure I understand what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: So you wan the sum based on the EventId is it?

Comment: I agree with @sgeddes.  You should supply a few sample output rows that you'd expect to see in your result set.

Answer (score 1):

This code sample is not complete - you need to enter the fields you need to display and aggregate upon.  It sounds like you're looking for a result that's between two dates, and you don't have that in your query.  I'm not sure I comletely understand your question.

```
DECLARE @pStartDate DATE
DECLARE @pEndDate DATE

SET @pStartDate = [enter your start date for the date range]
SET @pEndDate = [enter your end date for the date range]

SELECT
    COUNT(EventId),
    ValidFrom,
    ValidTo
FROM [Table]
WHERE
    ValidFrom >= @pStartDate
    AND ValidTo <= @pEndDate
    AND Approved = 1
GROUP BY
    ValidFrom,
    ValidTo
```

Comment: well yes i know its not complete that is why asking to suggest any way to achieve, well i have a calender control which fills the total events on the behalf of the active events on it,    Above Query just shows the event total based on the particular date only which is not desired

Answer (score 1):

This will do:

```
declare @dateFrom date
declare @dateTo date
SET @dateFrom = '20130101'
SET @dateTo = '20130501'
;with cte as(Select @dateFrom AS EveryDay
          UNION ALL 
          Select dateadd(dd, 1, EveryDay) FROM cte WHERE EveryDay < @dateTo)
SELECT
EveryDay,
COUNT(DISTINCT [EventName]) AS NoEvents
from cte LEFT JOIN Table1 ON ValidFrom <= EveryDay AND ValidTo >= EveryDay
GROUP BY EveryDay
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d7200/8)

Comment: hey cha , can you share the output result ?

Comment: I have provided the SQL Fiddle for you to play with. When you click on `Run SQL` button you will see the result

Comment: ahhh tnx its working without it but one thing more that the above query doesn't include the Approved=1 condition which is serving ambiguous result

Comment: I guess you can do it yourself. Just add WHERE Approved=1 line directly before GROUP BY clause. I have just given you the direction in which to follow: i.e. first create a cte for every day for the specified date range, and then count the number of events grouping by each day

Comment: yes i just have done it already but the result is ambiguous still as if you see at 2013-03-02 it shows only 1 event which should be more then 1

Comment: RE: 2013-03-02. I see 2 in my SQL Fiddle. Have you adjusted the SQL? Why do you see 1?

Comment: nice its working perfectly fine with minor changes  tnx cha :D

Comment: anyhow i used Convert(nvarchar,"DateTypeVariables", 101) in the where condition where ever i needed to check the date and it worked nicely

Answer (score 0):

With the above Query i have mentioned gives the result like this :-

```
Date    CountOf RowNumber
01/27/2013  2 Events    1
03/02/2013  1 Event         2
04/07/2013  2 Events    3
05/17/2013  1 Event         4
```

As you can see i am getting total events only on the base of particular date which is not desired.

i want to show the result as like in valid from =01/27/2013 in valid to 2013-05-10 which means in the case of Date =2013-03-02 the events should be incremented by one or the number of events which are active on that date,so the result for 2013-03-02 should be 6 events, i wish i can present a better picture but because of the complexity it made me blank :(

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.EventId,t1.Description,t1.EventName,t1.ValidFrom,t1.ValidTo,t1.Approved,SUM(TotalEvent) FROM
    (SELECT EventId,Description,EventName,ValidFrom,ValidTo,Approved,COUNT(EventId) as Total
    FROM TABLE
    WHERE Approved='1' AND ValidFrom >=(DATE)  AND ValidTO<=(DATE)
    GROUP BY EventId,Description,EventName,ValidFrom,ValidTo,Approved) AS t1
    LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT EventId, COUNT(EventId) as TotalEvent
     FROM TABLE
     WHERE ValidFrom >=(DATE)  AND ValidTO<=(DATE)) AS t2
     ON t1.EventId=t2.EventId
     Group by t1.EventId,t1.Description,t1.EventName,t1.ValidFrom,t1.ValidTo,t1.Approved
```

Hope this help you.

Comment: WHERE ValidFrom >=(DATE)  AND ValidTO<=(DATE)) AS t2
     LEFT JOIN 



i guess your are missing something here  as while running its giving me the error






     t1.EventId=t2.EventId
     Group by t1.EventId,t1.Description,t1.EventName,t1.ValidFrom,t1.ValidTo,t1.Approved

Comment: Try to play around it sure u can achieve it.